# How to put alert before check-uncheck a kendo checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, kendo-ui, treeview

So if a user wants to check a checkbox, it will prompt a dialog if he/she have rights to tick-untick. So when he don't have rights, the state will stay the same.

I am using angularjs with kendo treeview.

```
   $scope.options = {
   checkboxes: {
       checkChildren: true,
   },
   loadOnDemand: false,
   check: onCheck,
   dataSource: $scope.treeData,
   template: '{{ dataItem.text}}',
   schema: {
       model: {
           children: "List"
       }
   }


function onCheck(e) {
   var currentItem = e.sender.dataItem(e.node);
   console.log(currentItem.rights);
   //if currentItem.rights= '0001'
   //dataItem.checked = true else false (something like this)
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo UI's events sometime are very poorly designed. Example [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/uboNObAF): The `check` event is prevented but it still perform the change, what doesn't happens in the [default JS behaviour](https://jsfiddle.net/qzvnbzu3/2/). What you can do is a *rollback* on changes:

```
if (!window.confirm("Do you have the rights to change this?")) {
    window.setTimeout(function (node) {
        this.expand(node); // expand() creates the child list if not created yet
        $(node).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", null);
    }.bind(this, e.node));
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/uboNObAF/2)

IKR it is ugly, but I can't figure a better way for doing that. The nice thing is that the *checkbox* user's clicks, is not a real checkbox, it is a `span` that somehow internally changes the state of a real hidden checkbox and you [**can't** prevent it's default click behaviour!](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/uboNObAF/3) Maybe somebody in their forums could help with a better solution but I'm not sure about that.

**UPDATE**

In fact there was a logic error in the snippet. The `check` event should be:

```
check: function(e) {
    let dataItem = this.dataItem(e.node);

    if (!window.confirm("Do you have the rights to change this?")) {
        window.setTimeout(function (node, currentState) {
            this.expand(node); // Expand created the child list if not created yet
            $(node).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", (currentState ? "checked" : null));
            this.dataItem(node).set("checked", currentState);
        }.bind(this, e.node, !dataItem.checked));
    }
}
```

[Updated demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/uboNObAF/4).

The bug you've reported was happening because it was changing only the element state and not the DataItem's `checked` property, so internally the widget was acting wierd. Also, there was another bug that, the *cancel* action was only changing the checkbox to *unchecked* state and that was wrong, since the user could be *cenceling* a checked checkbox, so it state has to be kept checked.

Comment: Hi! Surely will not downvote you! 
I found a bug in this code:

1: Check a child node.
2: Click cancel in the prompt
3: check it again.
Tadaaa! the prompt will not be there. :(

Comment: After debugging your code, I think it is because after checking the 'checked' property it is in the state before the rollback. The rollback only takes effect in the UI side.

Comment: @dscythe sorry for the long delay dude, I missed your replies. Check it now.

Comment: Hey! This is now working! I came up with this solution also but without `}.bind(this, e.node, !dataItem.checked));` 
so thank you sir! You can change your name to UpvoteMe! Cheers!

Comment: @dscythe haha you're welcome. I have added that `bind` to make sure the callback called in `setTimeout` will have those variables set when called, but if works without it its really better to take it out. cheers

Comment: Hi! The problem arrises when I check the parent node-> the children nodes will be checked all and i cant redo and the pop up is gone.